# How to fix the Active Directory Authentication Issue with Ubuntu 16.04 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory

While trying to manually join a Linux Instance of Ubuntu 16.04 in AWS Manged Active Directory using the tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/join_linux_instance.html, the authentication to the realm succeeded, but after that I am getting this error while trying to join the UBuntu 16.04 instance to AD:

```
Couldn't authenticate to active directory: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: An invalid name was supplied (Success)
adcli: couldn't connect to ad.nettracer.aero domain: Couldn't authenticate to active directory: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: An invalid name was supplied (Success)
! Insufficient permissions to join the domain
realm: Couldn't join realm: Insufficient permissions to join the domain
```

however, the same is working for CentOS.

Is there is anything wrong happens from my end?

Comment: 13K views and its locked so updated information/answers can't be provided? come on...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have had the same issue with joining my Ubuntu 16.04 machine and all I had to do to resolve the problem is set the rdns flag to false in the krb5.conf as shown below:

***/etc/krb5.conf***

```
[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
# default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
```

Once you have added the line, you can join the machine to the domain by using the command:

> `sudo realm join -U join_account@EXAMPLE.COM example.com --verbose`

Comment: Wow, just wow.  Every time I think I understand integrating Linux and Windows environments I am humbled.

Comment: This answer saved me quite a bit of time. To add to the answer: I'm starting a VM on AWS with Ubuntu 20.04, so in the cloud-init user-data (the startup file), I'm joining the domain. For anybody that must join from a startup file: Before the line with `echo "password" realm join -U admin domain.com`, I've added `sed -i -e 's/\[libdefaults\]/[libdefaults]\n\trdns = false/g' /etc/krb5.conf`, which edits `/etc/krb5.conf` to add `rdns = false`, as this answer states.

Comment: I had the same error on Linux Mint 20 running on my own infrastructure. There was no /etc/ktb5.conf, but creating the file with content as above appears to have resolved the problem.